# How to reset a few commits and merges (via pull from origin) to pull from remote again?

Tags: git

I made changes to my local branch, committed those changes and pulled from the remote. Now I realise that I do not want to push those changes to that branch.

If I reset all the changes (including the changes from pull), upto the commit that I do not want, and then pull the remote branch. Would the local branch reflect the remote branch without the unwanted commit?

Comment: what do you mean ```reflect the remote branch without the unwanted commit?

git```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let’s call the sequence of events Change, Commit, Pull. Now you wish the commit were on a different branch. Do a hard reset to before the pull. That undoes the pull. Make your new branch but don’t get onto it. Now do a hard reset to before the commit. The commit is now on the other branch and you are safe to do the pull again.